# "Shop By " Feature in category page magento

Tags: magento

My problem is that I am using a theme in magento and using the `2-column left` layout of the template. I want to show the "*shop by*" feature in category page. when I search anything on the site it shows the "*shop by*" block  is the link of the site.

Please help

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Did you set anchor "YES" for catgeory from admin panel.admin panel->catalog->manage catgeory->open any category and set anchor "yes".also make sure that you didn,t remove "shop by" block reference from catalog xml file.hope it help